# Image doesn't loads on recyclerview from firebase database using picasso

Tags: android, https, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I have been trying to create a wallpaper app I have this activity with a recycler view. I want to load images from my firebase firestore database.I have managed to do that. I am getting the right image url as I checked it using LOG.I tried to convert the image link to images using `PICASSO`.But unfortunately, the images don't loads on the recyclerview. please Help

This is my Adapter and Holder class

```html
package com.example.rimapps.charpapers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Protocol;
import com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Rimshad on 28/11/2017.
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    List<String> Mylist2= new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(List<String>Mylist2,Context context) {
        this.Mylist2 = Mylist2;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.items2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
                .build();

       picasso.with(context)
                .load(Mylist2.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.superman)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(holder.image2);

        holder.image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context,Mylist2.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Mylist2.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


                public ImageView image2;

                ViewHolder(View view) {

                    super(view);

                    image2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wallid);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my MainActivity class

```html
package com.example.rimapps.charpapers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG ="tAAAAAAAAAAg" ;
    private ArrayList<String> imagelist;
    RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recview2);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(Main2Activity.this,2));
        imagelist= new ArrayList<>();
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Wallpapers").document("Aquaman");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
                         for(int i=1;i<document.getData().size();i++){
                            document.get(i+"");
                             imagelist.add(document.get(i+"").toString());
                             Log.e(TAG,document.get(i+"").toString());
                        }
                            ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(imagelist,Main2Activity.this);
                            recyclerView2.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }
            }
```

I want to load the images from the db to my recycler view

the current result am getting is the `.error(R.drawable.error)` from `picasso`.Please help. Is that a problem with https:

Comment: Are you sure youre getting proper url ?

Comment: Is there any logcat error?

Comment: yes I am getting the proper url..I just checked it in my browser by deleting the double quotes on both ends

Comment: Yah..now I get an error..no adapter attached skipping layout @ankitpatidar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is because, I cannot clearly specify it in comments:

There is no need of make this statement code:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
        .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
        .build();
```

You can directly call it by:

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(Mylist2.get(position))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.superman)
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .into(holder.image2);
```

Comment: I want to take data from database.not fro drawable @ankit patidar

Comment: Can you share your project with me? if you feel ok.

Comment: It has been solved.. The problem was picasso created another " quotes at both ends..I just split it..Thanks